# "Official" source channel to apt install a version of Python3

Tags: apt, package-management, python, ppa

My background is more on Windows and Mac, and much less on Ubuntu. Recently I need to write a script to install Python3.7 on a remote machine that runs Ubuntu 16.04. The related line of the script is

```
RUN apt-get update && apt -y install software-properties-common && add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && apt update && apt-get update && apt -y install python3 python3-pip python3.7
```

It works, but some code reviewers may doubt the trustworthiness of the `ppa:deadsnakes`.

"Why do we have to download from a third-party channel?" so I was questioned.

My questions are:

1. Does Python have an official channel for Ubuntu users to `apt` get?
2. Is there anyway to download and install a given version of Python3 from the *official* source? (Either the party in charge of Python or Ubuntu / `apt` repositories could be considered official.)

My experience in Ubuntu is limited. On Mac, I use `brew` to do so and the download link is from `Homebrew` so that at least *sounds* more trustworthy than "deadsnakes" (with all my respect to the maintainers). Please help and correct any of my misunderstanding. Thanks.

Comment: Do not replace or alter the system-provided version of Python 3.5.1 on your Ubuntu 16.04 system. Doing so will break your system. Look into how to use an environment manager like venv or conda to safely use multiple versions of Python3 on the same system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't mean to replace or alter that, however. I meant to download Python3.7 and use it as `Python3.7`, if possible. The question is how to do so in a more "official" way.